Counting Nested Ranges
With N ranges of the form [start, end] (both endpoints inclusive), I want to find, for each range, how many (other) ranges contain it and how many ranges it contains (are contained by it).
tl;dr count the number of ranges contained by each range, and count the number of ranges that contain each range.
This is the CSES Nested Ranges Count problem.
Definition: a range [s1, e1] contains range [s2, e2] if and only if s1 <= s2 and e2 <= e1.
N is a positive integer that can go up to 2*10⁵. All ranges have positive integer endpoints, each at most 10⁹. All ranges are distinct.
The time limit is 1 second. Here is my attempt, sadly it sdoes not pass because it's too slow.
#include <bits/extc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cin.tie(0), ios::sync_with_stdio(0), cout.tie(0);
    int N;
    cin >> N;

    vector<pair<int, int>>ranges;
    while (N--) {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        ranges.emplace_back(a, b);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) ranges.size(); i++) {
        int cnt=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < (int) ranges.size(); j++)
            cnt += i != j && ranges[i].first <= ranges[j].first && ranges[j].second <= ranges[i].second;
        cout << cnt << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) ranges.size(); i++) {
        int cnt =0;
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)ranges.size(); j++)
            cnt += i != j && ranges[j].first <= ranges[i].first && ranges[i].second<= ranges[j].second;
        cout << cnt << ' ';
    }
}

Sample input:
4
1 6
2 4
4 8
3 6

Sample output:
2 0 0 0
0 1 0 1

Explanation: the first line of output has the number of ranges contained by each range, in the order that the ranges were in the input, separated by spaces.
The second line has the number of ranges that contain each range, in the same order.
How can I solve this problem more efficiently (objectively: within the time limit)? Am I missing some algorithm?

int i = 0; i < (int) ranges.size(); should be size_t i = 0; i < ranges.size(); or auto i = 0U; i < ranges.size();

@273K wait I thought unsigned and size_t were different?

N is a positive integer that can go up to 210^5.* -- Given that N can be up to 200000, there is no way a double-nested for loop of N items is going to work to be within any time limit, let alone a second.  That would be 20000000000 iterations, plus you do this twice, giving a total of up to 40000000000 iterations.

My brain tells me there is a data structure for this that is better than N^2.

This is the CSES Nested Ranges Count problem -- Just to let you know, the type of questions that come from "competitive coding" websites are designed in a way so that you waste time coding naive solutions (such as nested for loops that go on forever) -- those solutions never work when the data set is large.  You need to research into the problem beforehand to find a better data structure and/or algorithms.

@PaulMcKenzie I know this solution is too slow, I just wrote it because I heard you need to show an attempt

@user24044002 But you do see that the real solution would look nothing like the attempt you are showing us.  You knew this beforehand.  I suggest you research into the question, as this question seems to have been asked many times on the web.  If you had instead showed a researched solution that has a bug, then that would have been more honest.

@PaulMcKenzie I did search on google with site stackoverflow. If I was able to find, I wouldn't ask here

Well, I googled "CSES Nested Ranges Count" and came up with several links, even a YT video, on this problem.

@PaulMcKenzie i admit I did not look on youtube, but I thought that stackoverflow users will answer better than randos on youtube. like am I not allowed to ask about a problem if i don't know how to solve it?

Here is the deal -- every competitive coding question has been solved, and probably solved by thousands of persons already.  The YT video(s) that show solutions are not going to teach you C++, as most C++ teaching videos should be avoided, as they are poor.  However those videos that give you information on the proper data structure(s) or algorithms to solve them, many of those videos are worthwhile.  At the very least, it would give you the hint(s) on how to solve the problem.  Also remember -- one of the reasons for downvotes here is "lack of research" -- don't fall into that trap.

@PaulMcKenzie do u have any ideas how you would approaching this then? i really don't see how to even start or how to make a thought process . im sorry for the dumb question

One of the things you can do with the slow-and-naïve first cut is study the output and execution to look for patterns you can exploit in the next version, so they aren't a complete waste of time. Though it is better to go into one of these competitions with a head-full of algorithms you can mix-n-match if one tried-and-true algorithm doesn't immediately present itself as the right way to go.

I had a go at solving this. My method is similar but a bit different from the one shown in the YouTube video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORdmSirqrMs as I wanted to use c and only my own data structures.
The 'trick' is to use a data structure that efficiently gives you the index position of an inserted element as if they were in an ordered list. I program in c mainly, and c doesn't have native support for complex data structures, so I implemented a Binary Search Tree (BST) which allowed me to insert elements and have returned the number of elements in the tree after insertion which are less than, equal to, and greater than the value I inserted. I denote these as lt, eq, and gt respectively. The BST works well for sufficiently random inserts with O(log n) time complexity, but without some form of self balancing, it has worst case O(n) insertion time. For example, suppose I've inserted 10, 34, 67, 132, and 15, then after inserting another element 66 I get lt = 3, eq = 1, gt = 2.
The algorithm I used goes as follows.
Sort Ranges on s_i ascending, e_i descending
CountingBSTinit();
for (i=0; i<Rangessize; i++) {
  CountingBSTinsert(&lt, &eq, &gt, Ranges[i].e);
  Ranges[i].contained = gt + eq - 1;
}
CountingBSTfree();
CountingBSTinit();
for (i=Rangessize-1; i>=0; i--) {
  CountingBSTinsert(&lt, &eq, &gt, Ranges[i].e);
  Ranges[i].contains = lt + eq - 1;
}
Unsort Ranges

I made an array of 200,000 random ranges as described in the problem statement and it solved it in just under 1s on my old Westmere laptop. I compared the results with those produced by a naive O(n^2) algorithm which took 2m 45s, over 150 times slower.
This is how I implemented the Counting version of the BST. If you have lt, eq, and gt at one node, then at the parent node, it should update to
if left node
  (lt, eq, gt) = (lt, eq, gt + parenteq + parentgt) 
  parentlt++
else 
  (lt, eq, gt) = (lt + parenteq + parentlt, eq, gt) 
  parentgt++

as you move back up the tree from the inserted node. I think it could be done more efficiently so you don't have to go back up the tree, but this is what I did. The extra node traversals don't change the time complexity of the inserts and if the visited nodes are still in cache, there may be little performance benefit to modifying the algorithm.

I put my program on GitHub here https://github.com/FastAsChuff/Counting-Binary-Search-Tree/tree/main

Thank u. I will try but an unbalanced bst will almost certainly TLE on CSES

We can simplify the problem by sorting all ranges in increasing order of starting points (and decreasing order of ending points for those with equal starting points). Then, every range is ordered before all ranges it might contain, so we only have to consider the end points while iterating through.
To find the number of ranges that each range contains, iterate backwards over the (sorted) ranges and for each range, find the number of ranges to the right of it in the container that have end point less than or equal to the current range's end.
To find the number of ranges containing each range, iterate forwards and for each ranges, find the number of ranges with a smaller index (in the sorted container of ranges) that have end point greater than or equal to the current range's end.
To maintain the collection of end points seen so far, we can either use a balanced binary search tree or coordinate compression (taking advantage of the offline nature of this problem) in conjunction with a binary indexed tree.
Both of these approaches have logarithmic time complexity for each insert and query operation.
CSES uses GCC, so it is simple to use the order statistic tree in its library of policy based data structures (which saves effort in implementing it manually).
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
template<typename Key, typename Compare = std::less<>>
using ordered_set = __gnu_pbds::tree<Key, __gnu_pbds::null_type, Compare, __gnu_pbds::rb_tree_tag, __gnu_pbds::tree_order_statistics_node_update>;
struct Range {
    int index, start, end;
};
int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<Range> ranges;
    ranges.reserve(n);
    for (int i = 0, start, end; std::cin >> start >> end; i++) ranges.emplace_back(i, start, end);
    std::ranges::sort(ranges, [](const auto& r1, const auto& r2) {
        return r1.start < r2.start || (r1.start == r2.start && r1.end > r2.end);
    });
    std::vector<int> contains(n), containedBy(n);
    ordered_set<std::pair<int, int>> prevEnds;
    for (const auto& r : std::views::reverse(ranges)) {
        contains[r.index] = prevEnds.order_of_key({r.end, n});
        prevEnds.insert({r.end, r.index});
    }
    prevEnds.clear();
    for (const auto& r : ranges) {
        containedBy[r.index] = prevEnds.size() - prevEnds.order_of_key({r.end, -1});
        prevEnds.insert({r.end, r.index});
    }
    std::ranges::copy(contains, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::ranges::copy(containedBy, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}


Does the order_of_key() functionality handle duplicate r.end values appropriately for this problem?

@SimonGoater Yes, because the tree is storing pairs and the index is unique.
